# extract only time from dateTime using query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

How can I extract or use only time from this `trades.tradedate` : `"2018-08-14 06:48:24"` using laravel query builder.

Output should be:
`06:48:24`
my function:

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);



    view()->composer('layouts.member', function ($view) {

        $user = optional(Auth::user())->id;
        $value = DB::table('exchanges')
            ->leftJoin('trades', 'exchanges.id', '=', 'trades.exchange_id')
            ->where('trades.user_id', $user)
            ->whereRaw("? NOT BETWEEN start_time AND close_time", 'trades.tradedate')

  OR   ->where('trade_date','>=', 'exchanges.close_time')->where('trade_date', '<=', 'exchanges.start_time')

            ->get();
        $view->with('value', $value);
    });

}
```

Comment: Please share your code what you have tried so far for better answers. Also you can try this way - date('H:i:s')

Comment: i have shared my code for you @Shreeraj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, but you can try something like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);



    view()->composer('layouts.member', function ($view) {

        $user = optional(Auth::user())->id;
        $value = DB::table('exchanges')
            ->leftJoin('trades', 'exchanges.id', '=', 'trades.exchange_id')
            ->where('trades.user_id', $user)
            ->select(DB::raw('TIME(trades.tradedate) AS trade_date'))
            ->whereRaw("? NOT BETWEEN start_time AND close_time", 'trade_date')

            ->get();
        $view->with('value', $value);
    });

}
```

Comment: this is good idea but, its giving me result as `trade_date` only. @Ahsan

Comment: i think you can override it by using TIME(trades.tradedate) AS tradedate ... but somehow i don't see it as a good practice

Comment: Or maybe you were referring to the fact that it just gives you this column, yeah by default it goes and select \*, but if you specify one select, you'll have to specify every column, or use ->selectRaw('\*')

Comment: Which result are you getting as `trade_date`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Carbon for parsing and get time from date.

For getting time from your model you can add method to your model:

```php
public function getTime ()
{
    return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($this->my_date)->toTimeString();
}
```

Or you can add accessor(getter fro attribute) for your model:

```php
public function getMyDateAttribute($date)
{
    return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($date)->toTimeString();
}
```

[More about accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators), [Carbon documentation.](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting)

Comment: I think i can not pass carbon.. let me post here my query

Comment: i have posted my function in question, `trades.tradedate` require to extract time.